# Run a java file located in a jar that is inside another jar

Tags: java, jar

I have a three folders i have compressed all the folders using jar. I want to access one of the java file inside jar file that is actually inside one of the folders to start the application. For example, I have **A and B folders inside folder A i have jar C**, I created **jar D that compresses A and B folder**.So A and B inside D jar, now i want to run a java file inside the jar C to start the application

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom class loader: See http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v1r4m2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.java.doc.diagnostics.142%2Fhtml%2Fid1100.html